Linear independence of Ramanujan sums
Let $r$ be a positive integer and define $c(n,r)=\sum_{d \mid (n,r)} \mu\left( \frac{r}{d} \right) d$ for all positive integer $n$ (Ramanujan sums). In the paper A class of Arithmetical Functons by Eckford Cohen, it is stated that if $d_1$ and $d_2$ are divisors of $r$, then
$$
\sum_{d \mid r} c \left( \frac{r}{d}, d_1 \right)  c \left( \frac{r}{d_2}, d \right) =  
\begin{cases}
    r & (d_1 = d_2) \\
    0 & (d_1 \neq d_2).
\end{cases}
$$
Then it is stated that the functions $c(n,d)$ are linearly independent for $d \mid r$, so I understand that $\sum_{d \mid r} \alpha(d) c(n,d)=0$ implies that $\alpha(d)=0$ for every $d \mid r$. However, I can't see how this follows from the above "orthogonality" equation.
What I've tried so far: given $\delta$ a fixed divisor of $r$, one can consider the summation
$$
\sum_{e \mid r} \left( \sum_{d \mid r} \alpha(d) c(n,d) \right) c(e,\delta)=0
$$
So
$$
\sum_{d \mid r} \alpha(d) \sum_{e \mid r} c\left(\frac{r}{e},\delta\right) c((n,r),d)=0
$$
where $(n,r)$ is the g.c.d of $n$ and $r$, since Ramanujan sums are even modulo $r$. I'd like to have $d=e$ in the inner sum and this would lead me to $\alpha(\delta)=0$, but I think this changes the overall sum. Thanks in advice.

It is the same as showing that non-zero orthogonal vectors are linearly independent: It is given that $\sum_{d\mid r}\alpha(d)c(n,d)=0$. Fix $d_0\mid r$, apply this to $n=\frac re$, multiply by $c(\frac{r}{d_0},e)$ and then sum over $e\mid r$:
\begin{align}
0=\sum_{e\mid r}\Big(\sum_{d\mid r}\alpha(d)c(\frac re,d)\Big)c(\frac r{d_0},e)&=\sum_{d\mid r}\alpha(d)\sum_{e\mid r}c(\frac re,d)c(\frac r{d_0},e)\\
&=\sum_{d\mid r}\alpha(d)\begin{cases}r& d=d_0\\0&d\ne d_0\end{cases}\\
&=\alpha(d_0)r.
\end{align}
So $\alpha(d_0)=0$ and since $d_0\mid r$ was arbitrary we are done.
